# BASH: find and rename files & directories

Tags: bash, sed, find

I would like to replace `:2f` with a `-` in all file/dir names and for some reason the one-liner below is not working, is there any simpler way to achieve this?

Directory name example:

```
AN :2f EXAMPLE
```

Command:

```
for i in $(find /tmp/ \( -iname ".*" -prune -o -iname "*:*" -print \)); do { mv $i $(echo $i | sed 's/\:2f/\-/pg'); }; done
```

Comment: `for` doesn't loop over `null` delimited strings.

Comment: Why are you using `-prune` here? you don't want to rename hidden files/directories? or is it just to skip `.`?

Comment: I just want to skip hidden files and dirs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to parse the output of `find`:

```
find . -depth -name '*:2f*' -execdir bash -c 'echo mv "$0" "${0//:2f/-}"' {} \;
```

We're using `-execdir` so that the command is executed from within the directory containing the found file. We're also using `-depth` so that the content of a directory is considered before the directory itself. All this to avoid problems if the `:2f` string appears in a directory name.

As is, this command is harmless and won't perform any renaming; it'll only show on the terminal what's going to be performed. Remove `echo` if you're happy with what you see.

This assumes you want to perform the renaming for all files and folders (recursively) in current directory.

`-execdir` might not be available for your version of `find`, though.

If your `find` doesn't support `-execdir`, you can get along without as so:

```
find . -depth -name '*:2f*' -exec bash -c 'dn=${0%/*} bn=${0##*/}; echo mv "$dn/$bn" "$dn/${bn//:2f/-}"' {} \;
```

Here, the trick is to separate the directory part from the filename part—that's what we store in `dn` (dirname) and `bn` (basename)—and then only change the `:2f` in the filename.

Comment: Thank you, would you be so kind to also explain this part of the code: `"${0//:2f/-}"`, could you please point me to some BASH manuals for this bit?

Comment: @HTF: You'll find information about this in the [_Shell Parameter Expansion_ section of the Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `bash: error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5: cannot open shared object file: Error 24`. Do you know if there is a way to pipe it to `xargs` to overcome open files limit?

Comment: @HTF: do you have a working Bash and what's its version? what OS are you on?

Comment: It's a `CentOS 6.5` server with `bash-4.1.2-29`. Bash is working fine but there are many file to rename/move.

Comment: @HTF, this `find` command treats each file separately! so there shouldn't be any error concerning the “open files limit”. Are you using exactly this command?

Comment: Yes, I just added exclusion for hidden files: `! -iname '.*'`

Comment: I've found this http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?34976 - "It seems that "find -execdir" is not very frugal with file
descriptors."

Comment: @HTF I've added a possibility that avoids the use of `-execdir`. See if that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have filenames containing space, `for` will split these up into separate arguments when iterating. Pipe to a while loop instead:

```
find /tmp/ \( -iname ".*" -prune -o -iname "*:*" -print \) | while read -r i; do
    mv "$i" "$(echo "$i" | sed 's/\:2f/\-/pg')"
```

Also quote all the variables and command substitutions.

This will work as long as you don't have any filenames containing newline.